# Looking for a reference for identifing stream regimes(Intermittent, Perennial)

Tags: hydrology, rivers, reference-request

I'm a hydrologist with a good background in GIS. I'm looking for a reference (Methodology, Technical guide) for identification of temporary, intermittent and perennial streams. I google and only found [this reference](https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_rm/rm_gtr245.pdf) for North Carolina.Is there any standard reference guide for such an identification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a standard per se, but I found it useful.  These definitions are from a 1923 publication of the United States Department of the Interior entitled Outline of Ground-Water Hydrology.  [Here](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/wsp494) is the link to the PDF and the specific definitions below can be found on pages 57-58.  Hope this helps.

Perennial:

- > A perennial stream, or stretch of a stream, is one which flows
  >   continuously. Perennial streams are generally fed in part by springs,
  >   and their upper surfaces generally stand lower than the water table in
  >   the localities through which they flow.

Intermittent streams are divided into spring-fed intermittent streams and surface-fed intermittent streams.

- > A spring-fed intermittent stream, or stretch of a stream, is one that
  >   flows only at certain times when it receives water from springs. The
  >   intermittent character of streams of this type is generally due to
  >   fluctuations of the water table whereby the stream channels stand a
  >   part of the time below and a part of the time above the water table.
  >   This is the ordinary type of intermittent stream.
- > A surface-fed intermittent stream, or stretch of a stream, is one that
  >   flows during protracted periods when it receives water from some
  >   surface source, generally the gradual and long-continued melting of
  >   snow in a mountainous or other cold tributary area. The term may be
  >   arbitrarily restricted to streams or stretches of streams that flow
  >   continuously during periods of at least one month.

Ephemeral:

- > An ephemeral stream, or stretch of a stream, is one that flows only in
  >   direct response to precipitation. It receives no water from springs
  >   and no long-continued supply from melting snow or other surface
  >   source. Its stream channel is at all times above the water table. The
  >   term may be arbitrarily restricted to streams or stretches of streams
  >   that do not flow continuously during periods of as much as one month.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kurt. But my question is about identification methods of these and to their definitions.

Comment: @wetland I think Kurt's point is: Look for the water.  In any particular case, where the water comes from will give you your answer.

Comment: @Spencer I think so. I didn't read the USGS document that Kurt recommended me. It's great.